# Turning off a server without HDD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssh

I used my old laptop as a home server for about a year. Recently a HDD in this notebook passed away, while the server still keeps running and providing the basic functionality (DNS, DHCP).

I expected this, since the hardware was really old and so I have a new server ready for a while,
all data backed up and services already set up.

The interesting problem that I ran into is the following: I can still ssh to the server and I get a tty allocated with a running shell. But I can't obviously run anything except the shell builtins.

Any ideas on how to shutdown the server? (I sure can press a button or unplug the power cord, but that is a boring solution).

The server runs Debian 9, but general ideas are also welcome.

Comment: Do you have a root shell on the machine?

Comment: Let's assume that I do, but sadly root uses different shell, which is not loaded in ram and so I don't.

Comment: Do you have a _running_ root shell on the machine? If not, you can’t.

Answer (score 1):

See [*Magic SysRq key*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key).

> The magic SysRq key is a key combination understood by the Linux kernel, which allows the user to perform various low-level commands regardless of the system's state. It is often used to recover from freezes, or to reboot a computer without corrupting the filesystem. Its effect is similar to the computer's hardware reset button (or power switch) but with many more options and much more control.

On a physically connected keyboard press <kbd>Alt <kbd>SysRq</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>o</kbd></kbd>. Maybe even <kbd>Alt <kbd>SysRq</kbd><kbd>o</kbd></kbd> would be enough.

<sup>(Your question mentions Debian. In some other Linux flavors one may need to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> *and* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.)</sup>

The full sequence is <kbd>Alt <kbd>SysRq</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>o</kbd></kbd> but since your HDD is dead and you want to virtually "unplug the power cord" the middle part is useless.

Without a physical keyboard attached (e.g. in an SSH session) one can do this by writing to `/proc/sysrq-trigger`:

```
echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger             # as root
echo o | sudo tee /proc/sysrq-trigger    # as a sudoer
```

This requires an elevated shell or working `sudo`. You probably no longer can have any of these. Hopefully the keyboard of the laptop in question works. In my laptop the SysRq key is labelled <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> and in KDE Plasma it works like PrintScreen. Still it possesses the magic of SysRq.

Comment: Also over a ssh connection?

Answer (score 0):

I would have some commands on how to shut it down if you have root:

1. poweroff
2. halt
3. shutdown -h now

See if one of these comamnds may be work. Good luck!

Comment: Any of these is not a shell builtin. Since the HDD is dead, there is no way of executing these binaries.